# React Native - login with Facebook - appears old app name

Tags: react-native

I changed the AppName. Previous name was Clark, current name is Mobify. However Facebook login dialog shows the older AppName. It is a react-native app.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more information to your question please? Can you add source code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to make sure that both `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName` are set in your `info.plist`.

Comment: Thanks. I change

Comment: I change:

<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>

to:

<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>AppName</string>

It help me